# What does git diff compare to if HEAD is detached?

Tags: git

From the man page (but I don't get it):

> git diff [--options] --cached [<commit>] [--] [<path>...]
>
> This form is to view the changes you staged for the next commit relative to the
> named <commit>. Typically you would want comparison with the latest commit, so
> if you do not give <commit>, it defaults to HEAD. If HEAD does not exist (e.g.
> unborn branches) and <commit> is not given, it shows all staged changes.
> --staged is a synonym of --cached.

Answer (score 3):

It makes no difference whether `HEAD` is detached or not. Detached `HEAD` does not mean that `HEAD` is not available, just that `HEAD` is pointing to some commit directly, not to a branch.

Comment: Cool. So how do I find out which branch it is comparing to? When I enter git status, it doesn't tell me a branch. Or can I compare my current work to a specific branch using diff?

Comment: If you don't give `diff` any parameters, you compare against the index. If you give it some commit-ish (a branch name is also a commit-ish), you compare against what you specify. If you give two commit-ishs, you compare those commit-ishs against each other. The variant you posted compares not your working tree against something, but the index against something, by default against the HEAD.

Comment: `git status` does tell either the branch or - if in detached mode - the commit HEAD is pointing to